# C#: Better way to refactor method to display appropriate groupbox and hide others?

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to refactor the following method which's purpose is to make sure the appropriate groupbox is the one displayed apart from the others as if they're cycled through a list? Is it possible to refactor this all into one solo if statement + "with no elses keywords"?

```
    // DisplayGroupBox(grpSounds);
    void DisplayGroupBox(GroupBox GroupBoxControls)
    {
        grpSounds.Visible = false;
        grpAlerts.Visible = false;
        grpFilters.Visible = false;

        GroupBox.Visible = true;
    }
```

Edited: I meant on ways to refactor in one statement to display appropriate groupbox with no else statements. Perhaps a way using the &&, ||, and such operators.

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to do. I'm guessing you have three groupboxes and you want to display only one of them at a time, but that's a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably just leave the method as is. You can squeeze all of those operations into one line, but the intent of the method won't be as clear. I think it is fine the way it is, no amount of refactoring can really make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your group boxes in a collection (i.e. just add grpSounds, grpAlerts, grpFilters to a list) you could do:

```
void DisplayGroupBox(GroupBox groupControlYouWantToDisplay)
{
    foreach(var box in listControls.Where(gb => gb != groupControlYouWantToDisplay)
       box.Visible = false;
    groupControlYouWantToDisplay.Visible = true;
}
```